# Computer freezes for a few seconds, strange disk activity

Tags: windows-10, freeze

From time to time, around once in two days, the computer freezes for around 5 or 10 seconds.

During that time, I can move the mouse but thats it. No application interaction and no keyboard response.

While investigating this, I noticed the following behavior in the task manager. The ssd seems to behaving in a weird way. 100% active with zero data transfers.

[image]

Zero read/write and 100% active. This is odd to me.

To further investigate the issue I used the [SSDlife utility](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/SSDlife-Free.shtml) but the results suggest that the disk is healthy.

[image]

Some notes that might help:

- No devices connected to the laptop
- Laptop touchpad and bluetooth also disabled
- Only a usb mouse connected
- No camera, sound or other devices used during that time
- No other strange laptop behavior

What can cause such a behavior or how can I further investigate the issue?

Comment: I doubt about that. The behavior presented in that question is when dealing with lots of little files that make the internal drive's cache in HDDs to behave that way. In my case there is an ssd. Also note that in that question the drive has activity, I have experienced that behavior in the past when copying/moving more than 10k files at once. I found it irrelevant here, since the numbers differ and I have an SSD.

Comment: Used to see similar "freezes" when an old HD would freeze for a few seconds

Comment: Do you have any AV software? My old McAfee installation used to do scans at 20:00 every Friday just as I was starting an evening of gaming. It produced similar disk activity and symptoms.

Comment: Have you checked for firmware updates for your ssd?

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point : Use Resource monitor while this activity is high and try to pinpoint the process / files that has to do with it. You can also use Perfmon to capture more data that can be posted for more exact answer. Other tools may prove to be helpful too, like : Process Explorer/Monitor, DiskMon/FileMon.. try to log as much data while the problem occurs. It may be a cache sync and a large flush to happen at times, if you have torrent clients it may be a result from large file dumps or some SSD garbage routine, but all are guesses until more data is captured, so you should start there.

Answer (score 0):

I have had these exact symptoms in the past and it could be the disk starting to fail.

Check Resource Monitor, specifically look at Disk Activity -> Response Time.

Nothing there should be over a few milliseconds.

edit: You need to be checking when the issue is occurring obviously, so leave it open :)